# Printf from a file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, printf

I have created a test example to send a signal from matlab and receive the response + plot. However the signal i want to send is much longer than the one in this example.
I have tried reading from a file but i cant use the printf function with a vector column.
 dont want to use fwrite either as only printf works. Any ideas on a solution?
Thanks

```
s = serial('COM3');
set(s,'BaudRate', 9600);
s.InputBufferSize = 6000;
fopen(s);

t = 1;
a = 0;
fprintf(s, '9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0')
while(t <= 10)
  a = fscanf(s, '%d');
  x(t,:) = [t a]
  t = t + 1;
  plot(x);
  drawnow;
  axis auto;
  grid on;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab's `fprintf` accepts arrays as arguments and prints each element according to your specified format:

```
a = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
fprintf(yourfile, '%d ', a);
```

Comment: Will this work with a column vector? i.e my input file has a newline between each number

Comment: You can first read your input data into a column vector (like `a` in the code above) and then use `fprintf` with it. I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do.